# sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected with a C file

Tags: c, syntax-error

I'm getting a confusing error message. I'm running MinGW on Windows XP 32-bit. When I attempt to compile the following code, I get an error message "./hello.c: line 4: Syntax error near unexpected token '('". Line 4 is at int main(...), I can't figure out what unexpected token is "near '('". I've tried using int main(void), but I get the same message. However, if I compile it without the "char string..." and "data = fputs(...)" and have it read from a given text file, it compiles without issue.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to read from a file where the filename is given by an external source, i.e. php. Eventually I'm going to be working this into an Apache module with a parser that I've made, hence the call from php, but I wanted to fool around and build some template code to work with before I got to that part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    //char string = "JD";    commented out
    char data;
    //printf("Type in your filename:   "); also commented out
    //scanf("%s", &argv);  also commented out

    if(argc >= 2)
    {
        fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r"); //switched to reading a given file
    }
    while((data = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        fgets(data, sizeof(data), fp);
        // data = fputs(string, fp);
    }

    if (fp==NULL) /* error opening file returns NULL */
    {
        printf("Could not open player file!\n"); /* error message */
        return 1; /* exit with failure */
    }
    /* while we're not at end of file */
    while (fgets(data, sizeof(string), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf(data); /* print the string */
    }

    fclose(fp); /* close the file */
    return 0; /* success */
}
```

Okay, I tried writing a simple "Hello World" program, but I'm still getting the same error message with it which makes me think the error message isn't being caused by my code at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) //still getting a syntax error before unexpected token '('
{
    printf("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...so what's in `myotherfile`?

Comment: Can you run the file from terminal?

Comment: Did u try compiling it?

Comment: @NishithJainMR Did you try looking at the code?

Comment: I tried it and it compiles, this is the output :sh: 1: ./myotherAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA: not found.I think you should tell more about ./motherfile.

Comment: I checked , its is compiling fine. May be issue is with "myotherfile". As @CarlNorum said , can you mention the content of the file?

Comment: `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` means the problem is not with your program (if it would have been true `gcc` would have produced error instead of `sh`). The problem is with the `command` you want to run.

Comment: Why are people talking about myotherfile? That's never used by the program ... only the first 9 chars, `./myother` are copied.

Comment: @CarlNorum The other file is just another file that takes the input. It is not used by this program at all and doesn't matter what there is in the other one.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong exactly?" -- It depends on what you *want* this to do, which you haven't stated.

Comment: *this is the output :sh: 1: ./myotherAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA: not found.* -- of course that's the output, because you don't have the exploit script file that the OP does. "I think you should tell more about ./motherfile." -- uh, no ... the OP should tell us about the exploit script file, which is the one that sh is complaining about.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain what I am trying to do

Comment: If that's what you want to do, then why did you write code that does something different? The only reason to scratch your head for 2 hours if if you have no understanding of the code you wrote and what it does. Why do you copy the first 9 chars of "./myotherfile" when you want the whole thing, including the terminating NUL? Why don't you insert a space if you want one?

Comment: P.S. When you find yourself scratching your head, don't keep doing it for 2 hours, get to work with a debugger and/or adding diagnostic printfs ... here, printing `command` would have immediately told you that it was malformed.

Answer (score -1):

There is problem with your logic . the "exploit" array would contain "./myotherAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:" which you are passing to system ..so problem are bound to happen

Comment: I want to pass "./myother AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (including the payload varliable)"

Comment: @orange: If thats the whole purpose of the program, then show us the contents of `./myother AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`. The problem is with your shell script that you have written in this file.

Comment: **..so problem are bound to happen** Can you explain what you want to say? Why the problem will happen if that file exists on correct path in the system.

Comment: Can you please explain your intention behind this line  memset(exploit, 'A', 20);

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to run ./motherfile...Then when you concatenate it with "exploit" name becomes "./myotherAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA " and not "./myotherfile AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", to give space concatenate it with a space first.

Comment: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" is argument to ./myother file , isn't it?I tried it in that way in my system by creating a file myother.It works fine.

Comment: Please change "./myother AAA..." to "./myotherfile AAA..." in your answer ... it isn't just the space that's missing. (And I deleted my previous comment, which was made before I saw the OP's edit.)

Comment: ok , but I think that's not an answer now , should I delete it?

Comment: Eh? The *first* string should be "./myotherAAA..."; only the second once should be "./myotherfile AAA..." ... no reason to delete your answer, just improve it. The OP's major problem is using strncpy, and with too small a value to boot. A simple strcpy would work. Or I suppose you could delete it because I just gave that answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
strncpy(command, "./myotherfile ", 9);
```

only copies the first 9 chars. Replace that with

```
strcpy(command, "./myotherfile ");
```

which should do what you want.

P.S. I suspect that you originally had

```
strncpy(command, "./myfile ", 9);
```

which would have worked, and you didn't change the 9 when you changed the length of the file name. There are entire books written on why couplings like this are a bad idea and what to do instead. In this case the simplest solution is to use strcpy so you don't need to mention the length.

Comment: I still get the same issue. I've updated my original code so it includes 14 instead of 9

Comment: @orange Then you're leaving some information out. Try printing `command` to verify what it contains, and check the return value from `system` to see if it actually ran. And what system are you running on? is myotherfile executable? What is in it?

Comment: The code that is init is in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131378/attempting-a-buffer-overflow

The output I get is `./vuln AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA((`

Comment: @orange Again, what system are you running on, is the file executable, and what does `system` return?

Comment: @orange The output you get from what? You've got programs producing commands that modify other programs ... you need to be precise. The program you have posted here doesn't have "vuln" in it.

Comment: Ubuntu 12 and yes the file is executable.
Do you just want me to add printf(system)? If yes it returns this ```sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
?%
  h./myotherfile AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA((```

The output if from printf(command)

Sorry vuln is myotherfile name. Sorry for all the confusion, I will try to keep it consistent.